# Python UDP socketserver returning empty message

Tags: python, sockets, udp, socketserver

I have a UDP socketserver program that I use to demonstrate how UDP works (code for the server and client are below). I run this on a server, then have the `client.py` program send a message and receive a reply. I am unfortunately running into an issue that seems to only occur on campus Wifi. On campus wifi, the client does not receive a response.

Troubleshooting with Wireshark shows the issue. For some reason the UDP server is responding with two UDP messages - one empty, and one containing the response message. These messages are recorded in Wireshark as coming in approximately 0.000002 seconds apart. On a wired network, the one with the response consistently comes first, and on Wifi, the empty message consistently comes first. Since the client is waiting for a single messages response, when the empty message returns, the client prints and exits, and the actual response is never seen.

I know I could write the client to listen for both messages and print out whichever one has the data, but I would rather try to figure out what's going on. Why is the socketserver responding with two messages in the first place, and how can I get it to only send one? OR at least to send the data first.

`server.py`:

```py
import socketserver


class MyUDPRequestHandler(socketserver.DatagramRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):

        data = self.request[0].strip()
        socket = self.request[1]
        # just send back the same data, but lower-cased
        socket.sendto(data.lower(), self.client_address)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with socketserver.UDPServer(("0.0.0.0", 9091), MyUDPRequestHandler) as server:
        server.serve_forever()
```

`client.py`:

```py
import socket

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9091
message = "NOW I AM SHOUTING"  # The UDP server will lowercase the message

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock.sendto(bytes(message + "\n", "utf-8"), (HOST, PORT))
received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8")

print("Sent:     {}".format(message))
print("Received: {}".format(received))
```

Comment: Does the mysterious behavior continue to occur if you temporarily remove the `.strip()` and `.lower()` calls from the `handle(self)` method?

Comment: So you are receiving two either way, but the order changes sometimes on wireless?

Comment: The order seems to change every time on wireless, and yes, I'm receiving two response messages either way.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The strip is necessary, and removing `lower()` does not change anything.

Comment: @Ryan How is the strip nessesary for debugging?

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b @JeremyFriesner - My apologies, I removed `strip()` and it also has no effect.

Comment: @Ryan What operating system are you on?

Comment: Does the server send an empty message even if you remove the send? Then it would be a problem with whatever is causing the handle presumably. You may need to show more code for the server.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b The code above is the entire code for the server. If I remove the send, the empty message still comes back

Comment: @Ryan Apologies, I didn’t see that you were using the sockerserver library instead of the default socket. Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've repeated the problem and it's `socketserver`.  Notice the definition of `DatagramRequestHandler` below:

```
class DatagramRequestHandler(BaseRequestHandler):

    """Define self.rfile and self.wfile for datagram sockets."""

    def setup(self):
        from io import BytesIO
        self.packet, self.socket = self.request
        self.rfile = BytesIO(self.packet)
        self.wfile = BytesIO()

    def finish(self):
        self.socket.sendto(self.wfile.getvalue(), self.client_address)
```

The packet is put into a buffer as `rfile` and should be read from there, then written back to the `wfile` buffer.  `finish` sends the packet.  The handler shouldn't call `sendto` itself:

```py
import socketserver

class MyUDPRequestHandler(socketserver.DatagramRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.rfile.read()
        self.wfile.write(data.strip().lower())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with socketserver.UDPServer(("0.0.0.0", 9091), MyUDPRequestHandler) as server:
        server.serve_forever()
```

But just using a simple socket as the server works fine too:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 9091))
while True:
    data, client = s.recvfrom(2048)
    s.sendto(data.strip().lower(), client)
```

Note that UDP packets are not guaranteed to be delivered or delivered in the same order, so the original code's issue with the two packets changing order isn't surprising.